How to specify commandline arguments to node in ROS2 yaml launch file?
I'm trying to launch rviz2 with a custom .rviz file. There doesn't seem to be documentation anywhere about how to pass this in.
There's answers on on how  to do it for .py launch files, but not for .yaml launch files.
launch:
  - node:
      pkg: "rviz2"
      exec: "rviz2"
      name: "rviz2_robot"
      args: "['-d', 'robot.rviz']"


I got it. It's just a straightforward string. This works:
args: "-d $(find-pkg-share robot_bringup)/rviz/robot.rviz"

However I had to add in my CMakeLists.txt the INSTALL directive so that my .rviz file gets installed in the package share folder under install/.
install(DIRECTORY rviz DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME})

